# Consistent 500ms delay on network comms on SOME winXP,win7 systems

Tags: sockets, tcp

We're having a problem with network performance on some WinXP and Windows 7 machines, but not all.

We'll issue a send() call, then recv() the response.  Logging system ticks to a log file, the application thinks the delay is on the recv() (almost exactly 500 ms + a 15 ms quantum every time).  However, Wireshark shows no significant delay at all from when the send packet actually goes out to the response coming in.  So, something appears either be blocking the send() for 500 ms, or the whole response gets delayed before the app sees it (which is up to 30K or so, so lots of packets).

Turning the Windows Firewall on or off does not do anything.  This computer has a Trend Micro trial installed, but unactivated and disabled.  Other computers with the problem have had other antivirus software, etc.

We've looked into Nagle and delayed ACK, and neither seems to be the culprit.  We're also using TCP_NODELAY just in case.  The TcpAckFrequency registry entry doesn't change anything either.

We're doing a single send(), and a single recv().  Nothing fancy.

Thinking it might be a problem with our using port 80 and having some unknown packet inspection choke on us, we tried different ports with the same effect.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

We have some expert users claiming that uninstalling the antivirus (even a disabled one) fixes it for them, but not all the time. Also, different systems are using different antivirus packages (this one has a disabled Trend Micro, others are Norton, etc)  It's weak evidence of something, perhaps...  I thought I'd mention it.

**EDIT 2**

Updated to make this non-Win7 specific as we've now found a WinXP system that behaves the same way.

Comment: What is your source of the logging timestamps? What do you use for the logging? Half a second is way too much for any respectable antivirus.

Comment: GetTickCount() before and after the send() and recv(), logged to a file. It's way too consistently 500 ms...  looks like some kind of timeout.

Comment: Try disabling all the non-microsoft LSPs installed.  Try booting into safe mode (with networking) and seeing if the problem goes away.  Try running on a "clean" machine with no additional software (including Trend Micro).